# How to import WebRTC into xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webrtc

I've built WebRTC.framework following the guide on webrtc.org (https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/ ) and I put it in my xcode project, so I created the bridging header to use it in swift classes and I wrote my code. Now, if I run my app, it seems to start but after the launch screen shows this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4D44F30C-3D0A-47FE-86CC-BAD092422D60/AppRTC.app/AppRTC
Reason: image not found
```

Can someone help me? what does "image not found" mean? Into the "gen" folder there are many folders with *.a files but I didn't import these.

Comment: Compiling with Xcode is not supported! What we do instead is compile using a script that runs ninja from Xcode. This is done with a custom run script action in the build phases of the generated project. This script will simply call ninja as you would when building from the command line....from the docs

Comment: I know, in fact I've built the framework from command line following the webrtc.org guide and after I put it into the the project.

Comment: Can you share the framework link you've built using the above procedure? I am not able to compile it on my machine. It is showing architecture x86_64 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add your framework in Target->Genral->Embedded Binaries.